# React TypeError: Non-iterable spread error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-scripts

```
    let headerKeys = {
      eventKey: '',
      content: ''
    };

    let bodyKeys = {
      eventKey: '',
      content: ''
    };
    
      headerKeys = otherSites.map(function (site) {
        return {
          eventKey: site.pk,
          content: <Link className={styles.linkStyle} to={`/console/customer/${customerPk}/site/${site.pk}`}>{site.name}</Link>
        };
      });

      bodyKeys = otherSites.map(function (site) {
        return {
          eventKey: site.pk,
          content: <CustomerSite
            customerSiteInformation={site}
            customerPk={customerPk}
            name={'site' +' '+ site.pk}/>
        };
      });
    }
    const header = [
      {
        eventKey: 'primary',
        content: <Link className={styles.linkStyle} to={`/console/customer/${customerPk}/site/${primarySitePk}`}>{primarySiteName}</Link>
      },
      ...headerKeys
    ];
    const body = [
      {
        eventKey: 'primary',
        content: <CustomerSite
          customerSiteInformation={primarySite}
          customerPk={customerPk}
          name={'primary site'}/>
      },
      ...bodyKeys
    ];
```

The above is the snippet of code where the spread error is coming up. I am getting the below error after updating the react scripts to 2.8. I am not sure how to use the **spread** operator in another way to bypass it. I have not defined any babel plugin since I ejected the create-react-app and did not need it. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
**Error as follows**

TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
_nonIterableSpread
node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/nonIterableSpread.js:2
  1 | export default function _nonIterableSpread() {
> 2 |   throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance");
  3 | }
View compiled
_toConsumableArray
node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/toConsumableArray.js:5
  2 | import iterableToArray from "./iterableToArray";
  3 | import nonIterableSpread from "./nonIterableSpread";
  4 | export default function _toConsumableArray(arr) {
> 5 |   return arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || iterableToArray(arr) || nonIterableSpread();
  6 | }
View compiled
CustomerSitesContainer.render
src/containers/CustomerSiteContainer.js:123
  120 |   });
  121 | }
  122 | const header = [
> 123 |   {`enter code here`
      | ^  124 |     eventKey: 'primary',
  125 |     content: <Link className={styles.linkStyle} to={`/console/customer/${customerPk}/site/${primarySitePk}`}>{primarySiteName}</Link>
  126 |   },
View compiled
```

Comment: The error might be that you want to spread out an object with keys and values and put it inside an array. It would be helpful if you provided a link to your code, if you have it on CodePen or any other website, so that I can try a solution.

Comment: You've a dangling closing bracket (`}`) line above `const header = [`.

Comment: @ArnoldGee
This is the codepen link

Comment: @ArnoldGee https://codepen.io/immortalstar7/pen/WNwxVJx